# Actionscript : 1087: Syntax error: extra characters found after end of program

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, actionscript, import, filenames

I tried importing a .as referring to my variable name/value

```
import "net.chars."+adc;
```

Comment: As answered, it cant be done (and makes no sense to do it anyway). What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't dynamically import a path via a string, because AS3 imports occur as compile-time. They're simply directives to tell the compiler what classes/packages you're using, nothing more.

You might be able to use the `getDefinitionByName` function if you really need this functionality, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/685059/465378). However, you should note that you still have to reference the class somewhere in your code, otherwise it won't get compiled into the SWF. Flash has no way of loading classes externally at runtime, so you have to ensure that the compiler knows to include it.

For more information, see [this article](http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2010/09/loading-classes-dynamically-in-actionscript-3.html).